# ARC, Nib files, and releasing top-level objects

Tags: cocoa, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting, nib

I have a custom controller object that loads a Nib file like so:

```
- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        [NSBundle loadNibNamed:@"AccountSetup" owner:self];
    }
    return self;
}
```

The Nib file contains a single `NSTabView` item. I noticed that when my custom controller object is released the *tab view is not released along with it*.

My custom controller object extends `NSViewController` and from what I read in the docs(1), top level objects in a Nib should be released automatically if the file's owner extends `NSViewController`:

> If the **File’s Owner is not an instance of NSWindowController or
>   NSViewController**, then you need to decrement the reference count of
>   the top level objects yourself.

If I release the tab view in `dealloc` of the custom controller it goes away correctly, but I'm wondering if I'm missing something or if the docs are just not very precise in this particular case.

1) https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/CocoaNibs/CocoaNibs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000051i-CH4-SW18

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your controller is a subclass of `NSViewController`, then you are using it incorrectly and bypassing its nib loading mechanism. You should be doing this:

```
- (id)init 
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:@"AccountSetup" bundle:nil];
    if (self) 
    {
        //perform any initializations
    }
    return self;
}
```

By bypassing the `initWithNibName:bundle:` method and using the `NSBundle` method directly, you are preventing `NSViewController` from managing the top-level objects in the nib.